# Column name is invalid while using SQL joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I came across a problem that I do not understand.

```
SELECT T1.CUSTOMER_ID,CONVERT(DATE,T1.DOB,105)   [DATE_OF_BIRTH],
    T2.TOTAL_AMT,
    DATEDIFF(YEAR,CONVERT(DATE,T1.DOB,105), GETDATE()) as AGE
FROM CUSTOMER T1
  INNER JOIN TRANSACTIONS T2 ON T1.CUSTOMER_ID=T2.CUST_ID
WHERE AGE>=25 and AGE <=35
```

Whenever I run this query it gives an error:

> age is an invalid column

I am trying to find out those customers whose age lies between 25 to 35.

Comment: 1) Please don't YELL. 2) MySQL or SQL Server 3) Please use the code format option in the editor to make your question readable.

Comment: Age doesn't exist yet, since WHERE is evaluated before the SELECT list.

Answer (score 1):

In your query, Age doesn't exist yet, since `WHERE` is evaluated before the `SELECT` list.

Use a `derived table`:

```
select * from
(
  SELECT T1.CUSTOMER_ID,CONVERT(DATE,T1.DOB,105)   [DATE_OF_BIRTH],
      T2.TOTAL_AMT,
      DATEDIFF(YEAR,CONVERT(DATE,T1.DOB,105), GETDATE()) as AGE
  FROM CUSTOMER T1
    INNER JOIN TRANSACTIONS T2 ON T1.CUSTOMER_ID=T2.CUST_ID
) dt
WHERE AGE>=25 and AGE <=35
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about logical query processing?

```
SELECT T1.CUSTOMER_ID,CONVERT(DATE,T1.DOB,105) [DATE_OF_BIRTH],
    T2.TOTAL_AMT,
    DATEDIFF(YEAR,CONVERT(DATE,T1.DOB,105), GETDATE()) as AGE
FROM CUSTOMER T1
  INNER JOIN TRANSACTIONS T2 ON T1.CUSTOMER_ID=T2.CUST_ID
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR,CONVERT(DATE,T1.DOB,105), GETDATE()) >=25 and         
DATEDIFF(YEAR,CONVERT(DATE,T1.DOB,105), GETDATE()) <= 35
```

Comment: Did you forget the code format button?